# How to create URL for Pages/Posts

Tags: urls, slug

I am not able to create a URL in WordPress like:

```
www.example.com/lp/time-cost/free-trial
```

When I add this URL, it's automatically changes to:

```
wwww.example.com/lptime-costfree-trial
```

Why are the slashes removed automatically?

Comment: That´s totally correct behaviour of the WordPress permalink engine, you are not supposed to add slashes, dots or special characters like that in your URLs.

Comment: So which way did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

To get URL like `www.example.com/lp/time-cost/free-trial` you need to create parent child pages.

1. Create `lp` as parent page
2. Create `time-cost` as child page of above (lp page)
3. Create `free-trial` as child page of (time-cost) page

Then if you access `free-trial` page you will get the URL like you want.

Comment: You can then, of course, access all those parent pages, too, as they are valid pages. Not sure if switch their status to "Review" would help, if you don´t want to have them accessible.

Comment: i know this solution, but i dont want to give access the people of parent pages.. only i want to give access to them only child page lp/time-cost/free-trial  , is there any other way we can achieve this, any plugin available for this??

Comment: this is not good way, i want to create these type of pages  1)lp/time-cost/freetrial  2)lp/time-bill/freetrial  2)lp/time-off/freetrial   like this i will create 200 pages like this, so according to your solution i should create 600 pages including parent->child->child  right???

Comment: Yes. No plugin to achieve what you want. Also, you cannot use ` / ` in the url string as you want. ` / ` means something rather important in the /site navigation scheme. If you don't want people to have access to parent pages, then I feel what you want to do is not necessary. If you think that the URL structure you are looking for will help you in SEO then thats not the case. The quality content is sufficient for SEO.

Comment: Just in case you decide to go with creating parent-child pages to achieve the desired URL structure and don't want to give access to parent pages, then use [this plugin] (https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) to redirect from parent pages.